# AVAudioSession setCategory return alway error

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I'm developing music application that simply play song from app. now i'm connecting bluetooth speaker to play. so i'm setting `AVAudioSession` category, but it will always return error.

**Code :**

```
 func setupSessionForPlaying() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [.allowBluetooth])
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Error Setting Up Audio Session")
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`.

But if i change `setCategory` to `audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)` its working fine.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

According to docs
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616518-allowbluetooth

> You can set this option only if the audio session category is playAndRecord or record.

with **allowBluetooth** you can not use  `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 4):

You cannot mix all categories with all options. As is mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616518-allowbluetooth) you may only use `.allowBluetooth` with the categories `playAndRecord` or `record`. So I suggest you to try

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                                                        with: [.allowBluetooth,
                                                               .allowBluetoothA2DP])
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566135/2328732) is the correct one in this particular case (due to the `.allowBluetooth` option), there is another possible reason for the 'what' error to appear:

The `AVAudioSession` could be currently playing or recording the moment `setCategory` is called. Make sure that the session is stopped before you set the category.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@Geru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566158/354876)

I got this error when using any combination of [.allowAirPlay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771736-allowairplay), [.allowBluetoothA2DP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771735-allowbluetootha2dp), and [.allowBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616518-allowbluetooth) with the [AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback) category.

```
Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed. The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)
```

This works, though:

```swift
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
} catch {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed. \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```